# router.navigate is now working with guard

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular9, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm making wep ap with angular 9 and asp.net core 3.1.

I made a guard to protect a url ("/perfil"). It use a service to get a cookie, if the cookie exist redirect to ("/perfil") if not redirect to ("/pre-register").

I've tried and when not exist the cookie works fine because redirect to ("/pre-register"), but when the cookie exist don't redirect to url ("/perfil").

I tested the cookie with backend code and this work fine.

canActive code:

```
      canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

    var validation = false;

    this.userService.cookieValidation().subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data == 1) {
        validation = true;
      }
      else {
        this.router.navigate(["/pre-register"]);
      }
    });

    return validation;
}
```

Redirect code

```
this.userService.userRegisterEmail(this.formLogin.value).subscribe((data: any) => {

      console.log(data);

      if (data == 2) {
        this.submitEmailRepeat = true;
        this.touchedEmailRepeat = true;
      }

      if (data == 0) {
        this.router.navigate(["/error"]);
      }

      if (data == 1) {
        this.router.navigate(["/perfil"]);

      }

    });
```

Comment: have you tried with single quotes? e,g

   this.router.navigate(['/login']);

Comment: Another issue with your code is that you should never call `route.navigate` from a route guard! If you want to redirect you should return a `UrlTree` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
this.userService.cookieValidation().subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data == 1) {
        validation = true;
      }
      else {
        this.router.navigate(["/pre-register"]);
      }
    });
```

this is asynchronous. It means that it doesn't happen in the sequence that you wrote it, but rather gets put on 'hold.'

So, what is effectively happening in your code is that you are putting that on hold, and then returning `validation` which you just equaled to false. So you are always returning false, no matter what happens inside your subscribe. Actually, the fact that you are returning false and it re-routes to where you want it to re-route only tells me that you have in your router a default route which is `pre-register`

A solution would be to return the Observable directly,

```
return this.userService.cookieValidation().pipe(
    map((data: any) => {
      if (data == 1) {
        return true;
      }
      else {
        this.router.navigate(["/pre-register"]);
        return false;
      }
    }));
```

notice that you are not subscribing to it, but returning it directly (and mapping it so it transforms whatever you get into a boolean, please refer to map operator for rxjs for more information). I'm unsure if returning this observable would work though, but I believe it should.